# Interval continue working after onErrorResumeNext

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive

I´m using Interval operator, and I want to continue emitting items even if a Exception happens on my pipeline.

So I try to use `onErrorResumeNext` emitting an item in case of Exception. But I seen that after emitt this item, the interval stop emitting more items.

Here my unit test.

```
@Test
public void testIntervalObservableWithError() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(time -> "item\n")
            .map(item -> item = null)
            .map(String::toString)
            .onErrorResumeNext(t-> Observable.just("item with error emitted"))
            .subscribe(System.out::print, t->{
                        System.out.println(t);
                    }
                   );
    TestSubscriber testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription);
    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I´m confuse with this behaviour, why the observable unsubscribe if it´s receiving an item from `onErrorResumeNext`

**SOLUTION:**

After some explanations, I realize that when an error happens the observable t´s complete. So I end up wrapping that observable that can have an exception into another observable and I´m using flatMap. So then the main Observable continue emitting items.

```
@Test
public void testIntervalObservableWithError() {
    Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(time -> "item\n")
            .flatMap(item -> Observable.just(item)
                    .map(String::toString))
            .subscribe(System.out::print); 
    TestSubscriber testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber();
    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

If there´s any operator that can do all that magic I would like to know.

Regrads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subscription interrupts because when `onErrorResumeNext` is triggered, your upstream already finished with an error. And you just emit an item instead of let exception goes downstream. In order to keep upstream alive you have to prevent exception to be thrown on it.

For your particular example solution can be like this:

```
...
    .map(time -> "item\n")
    .map(item -> item = null)
    .map(item -> {
        try {
            return item.toString();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return "item with error emitted";
    })
    //no onErrorResumeNext()
    .subscribe ...
```

`onErrorResumeNext` just replaces error with an item and calls `onComplete`.

Comment: Hi, please read my code example. I'm using onErrorResumeNext and it's not working.

Comment: I initially read your code. In your case it's impossible to keep `interval` alive, because you call ` .map(String::toString)` on a null item, stream immediately ends up with an error and this error gets caught by `onResumeErrorNext()`, that emits an item and stream calls `onComplete`. That's the answer to your question **why the observable unsubscribe?**. Also i updated my answer.

Comment: The wrap try/catch is what I figure yesterday, but it's a terrible solution. Wonder why an operator cannot do this.

Comment: It's because stream cannot be like this - ...item, item, error, item... If there is error then stream finishes immediately. To avoid try-catch you have only 1 option - convert operation that may throw an error to observable (or completable) and apply `onErrorResumeNext` on it, as i proposed before.

Comment: Yep that´s what I did. I did not realize that you told me to wrap into another observable, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The contract used by RxJava streams is that once an error is emitted no more items should be emitted. If your use case demands that the stream continues after the error then you need to convert the error into an an `onNext` emission as well. Create a wrapper type say `ValueOrError<T>` and start thinking in terms of `Observable<ValueOrError<T>>`:

```
Observable<Integer> source = ...
Observable<ValueOrError<Integer>> o = 
  source.map(x -> {
    try { 
      return new ValueOrError<>(mightThrow(x)); 
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      return new ValueOrError<>(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example to keep calling http service on error using onErrorResumeNext. Spent hours to find how it is supposed to work (new to RxJs), but understood it finally from @Maksim Ostrovidov's comment, so posting it here.
You can test it in chrome by switching offline checkbox in dev tools "Network Tab"

```js
var interval = 1000;
timer(0, interval).pipe(
          switchMap(_ => this.http.get('api/health').pipe(onErrorResumeNext()))
        ).subscribe(response => this.savedResponse = response);
```